# Как настроить размер картинки в header? com.mikepenz:materialdrawer

Tags: java, android

Библиотека

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.6@aar') { transitive = true }
```

Динамически создаю `NavigationDrawer` и Header для него я создаю с помощью

```
AccountHeader accountHeader = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.main_icon)
            .build();
```

и потом его добавляю в

```
drawer = new DrawerBuilder(this)
            .withActivity(ActivityHome.this)
            .withAccountHeader(accountHeader)
            .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(true)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .addDrawerItems(primaryDrawerItems)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
            .build();
```

ресурс изображения в `header` добавляется в этом методе `.withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.main_icon)` и в итоге это выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать, чтоб картинка не растягивалась?

Comment: Ну, наверное в исходниках/доках порыться к этому стороннему решению в поисках ответа. Если вы сами не нашли, то могли бы, хотя бы, привести ссылку на используемую либу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а да) забыл, сорри) Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Всё ж ссылкой-то удобнее, чем зависимостью...

Comment: Почему не воспользоваться стандартным решением?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Юрий, а подскажите как найти ссылку? Вот допустим у меня в манифесте есть зависимость как по ней найти где лежит сама библиотека?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, просто вбить в гугл... Первой же ссылкой обычно идёт либа на гитХабе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [исходниках AccountHeader](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/AccountHeader.java) есть метод `getHeaderBackgroundView`

```
 /**
 * Returns the header background view so the dev can set everything on it
 *
 * @return
 */
public ImageView getHeaderBackgroundView() {
    return mAccountHeaderBuilder.mAccountHeaderBackground;
}
```

Вызовите его и назначьте нужные параметры для отображения картинки. В вашем случае, думаю, `ScaleType` надо назначить другой. Например `centerInside`